# Streams backport compile error

Tags: java-stream, java-7

Using [streamsupport](https://github.com/stefan-zobel/streamsupport) with a Java 7 `javac` compiler I encounter the following compile error:

> [ERROR] method map in interface java8.util.stream.Stream<T>
>   cannot be applied to given types; [ERROR] required:
>   java8.util.function.Function<? super java.lang.Object,? extends
>   R>
>
> [ERROR] found: <anonymous
>   java8.util.function.Function<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String>> [ERROR] reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that
>   argument type <anonymous
>   java8.util.function.Function<java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String>> conforms to formal parameter type java8.util.function.Function<?
>   super java.lang.Object,? extends R>

My code is

```
List<Object> listSum = RefStreams.iterate(0, new UnaryOperator<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(Integer n) {
                return n+1;
            }
        }).limit(10000).map(new Function<Integer,String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(Integer n) {
                return String.format("%04d", n);
            }

        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to know what to do and why this error occurred? Thanks

Comment: please paste your code and not show screenshots. plus this is not a java-7 feature, it's java-8

Comment: In Java 7 [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) is unknown / exists since java 8. As it seems you want all that nice stream functionality, yet another argument to switch to java 8/9.

Comment: what is `java8.util.stream`? is this a copy paste of the source of java8 which can be used in java7?

Comment: I imported streamsupport.

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.streamsupport</groupId>
      <artifactId>streamsupport</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: @Lino *is this a copy paste of the source of java8 which can be used in java7?* That description is not far-off. It's the [streamsupport library](https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport) which is just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to be prepared that type inference in Java 6 / 7 compilers is not up to par with Java 8 / Java 9 compilers.
So, sometimes a statement / expression that compiles with 8 can't be compiled unchanged with 6 or 7. Providing a type witness usually helps the compiler figure out the correct types in Java 6 / 7.

I would do it this way (this works for me with javac from Oracle JDK 1.7.0_80):

```
List<String> list = RefStreams.<Integer, Integer>iterate(0, new UnaryOperator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer n) {
        return n + 1;
    }
}).limit(10000).map(new Function<Integer, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Integer n) {
        return String.format("%04d", n);
    }
}).collect(Collectors.<String>toList());
```

Note the two type witnesses here:

`RefStreams.<Integer, Integer>iterate` and `Collectors.<String>toList`.

The first is there to help the compiler infer the correct type for the `map` call and the second is there so that the result is correctly inferred as `List<String>` instead of `List<Object>`.